# Handling large amount of SSE subscribers coming in a short time window in Spring Flux

Tags: java, spring-integration, project-reactor, spring-webflux

Here is the problem case. When sse client (either web browser or mobile) is behind some specific network infrastructure with a certain proxy/firewall rules, it seems can't keep "long" connections. As a result it constantly keeps reconnecting to sse end-point "GET /sse" and hence subscribing to the same thing over and over again, multiplying subscribers count on server. There can be a bunch of reconnects per second from the same client which adds a bunch of new subscribers to a Flux. By the look of it, what happens is that the client "thinks" that connection was dropped and subscribes again,  server  adds a new subscription but do not release the previous ones from this client, since subscribers count only grows. What would be a proper way to handle/control such a flooding? My guess is to add to the flow chain doOnSubscribe() method and check if this client already has an active subscription, and in the case it does - cancel a new subscription. The question is how it could be checked. Or is there any better way? Thanks for any ideas!

Using Spring Boot (v2.0.0.M6) and Flux sse end-point.

Here is the relevant code:

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/sse", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<MyMessage> appMainChannel() {
        return Flux.from(httpReactiveSource)
               .filter(...)
               .limitRate(1)                
               .map(Message::getPayload)
               .cast(MyMessage.class);
}

@Bean       
public Publisher<Message<String>> httpReactiveSource() {        
    return IntegrationFlows.
            from(mainPubChannel())                                
            .channel(mainSSEOutChannel())                
            .toReactivePublisher();
}
```

Under other circumstances, i.e. in the network without those specific rules, all looks good.

Comment: How do you know that the number of subscriptions increases? When a client disconnects, the assotiated subscription should be cancelled. You can add `log()` or `doOn` operators to see what's going on.

Comment: Hi Brian, I refer to the number from the log output `INFO 8312 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'application:dev:8080.mainSSEOutChannel' has 882 subscriber(s).` Actually, server does release some subscribers but with much less  speed vs. new ones get created. So down the log I could see 881, 880, 879, but then it gets increased drastically by a new portion of reconnections.

Comment: Is the server writing to the stream constantly? Otherwise from the server point of view, we might only see a disconnection when we try to write to a connection.

Comment: It is not necessary constantly, but quite often. Also the problem is that by the look of it , the client gets "confused" by the network and opens a new connection leaving the previous ones opened too. Is there any way on server side to control/limit connections/subscribes from the same client? Lets say allow only 2 and everything whats beyond gets canceled?

Comment: I don't think there is a consistent way of doing that, especially since 1) clients come and go all the time 2) network infra makes it harder to guess if a single client is behind multiple connections 3) you can have multiple server instances and you'd need to maintain a shared registry of some sort